# C++ - How are multi-dimensional vectors stored?

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have two questions with respect to vectors.

1. Let us say I have a multi-dimensional vector as follows :-

   `vector< vector<int> > A;`

   Then `A[0]`, `A[1]`, etc are vectors. How are the vectors stored in `A`? I
    mean what information about the vectors `A[0]` and `A[1]` is stored in `A`? 
    And does memory re-allocation of the individual vectors such as `A[2]`
    cause re-allocation of `A` as well?
2. Second, I tried to see how the addresses of a vector change with re-allocation. I used the following code:-

**Code:**

```
vector<int> A;
int* x ;
int* y ;

vector<int>* ad;
vector<int>* bd;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++){

    A.push_back(i);
    if(i == 2){
        y = &A[0];
        ad = &A;
    }
    x = &A[0];
    bd = &A;    

}
```

I found that, the address for `A` does not change even though the address for `A[0]` changes. This is to be expected since vectors work in the background by making use of `new` and `delete`. But my question is how much information (or which information) about the vector is stored in the address `&A` (considering the address of `&A` does not change ). This is the question I have with respect to the first question as well.

I am trying to better understand how vectors work by default.

Comment: It is quite simple: an `std::vector<X>` contains `X` objects, regardless of the type of `X` (with the possible exception of `std::vector<bool>`.)

Comment: `What is stored in A` Elements of type `vector<int>`, of course, seeing as `A`'s type is `vector<vector<int>>` (and not `vector<T*>` for some type `T`). `I suspect that it stores the pointers` And what do you base said suspicion on?

Comment: STL isn't the same as the c++ standard library.

Comment: `how much information ... is stored in the address &A` Just enough information to locate the memory representation of `A`, of course. As is true for an address of any object.

Comment: I made some changes to the original question based on your comment @Igor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how much information (or which information) about the vector is stored in the address `&A`

You are correct in assuming that the data for the vector is stored separately from the vector object itself - typically, in dynamic memory.

The three things the vector object itself needs to know are

- **The location of the vector's data** - we need this to perform the `[]` operator,
- **The size currently allocated** - we need this to know when to grow the array, and
- **The number of elements actually placed into the vector** - we need this to know where to `push_back`, and what to return from `size()`.

Different implementations are possible, storing as little as a single pointer in the vector object itself. However, a typical implementation stores a pointer to the beginning of the allocated block, a pointer to the end of the active part of the allocated block, and a pointer to the end of the allocated block.

Comment: So , if I have a vector of vector of int, like A (in question 1) , it's memory will not be re-allocated, if I add elements to the one-dimensional vectors . But if I add a new one-d vector to A , it's memory might need to be re-allocated. I had these questions because this method of storage is quite different as compared to multi-dimensional arrays. ( I have used arrays a lot but not vectors )

Comment: @ameyask86 You are correct, adding to inner vectors does not result in re-allocation of the outer vector. The storage model of 2D arrays vs. vectors of vectors is very different. There are situations when this becomes important - for example, when you optimize CPU cache access strategy: a program with long, narrow 2D array could get significantly better performance than a program with vector of vectors of the same size.

Answer (score 2):

**Regarding the vector's address**: The address of `A` does not change, not because A is a vector, but because *no* variable's address changes while the function where you define it (or rather, the specific call of your function) is executing. I think you may be confusing A's address (ad, bd in your example) with the address of what A uses to store the elements of the vector (x and y,  essentially, in your example). Vectors allocate, de-allocate or re-allocate storage.

Note that `A[0]` is not a variable that you defined. It is the result of the invocation of `A.operator[]`; so its location *can* change.

**Regarding what's actually stored at `&A`**: That is kind of complicated. You will need to look at the header file `vector` within your C++ installation. Or perhaps it would be better to have a look at the [webpage for std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/vector) at [cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com/). Note there's a lot of templates, and some subclassing, and some explicit template specializations, so like I said - complicated. You might want reconsider whether you *really* want to look under the hood just to understand how this container works as a general rule, or whether the class' public methods and `sizeof()` figure are sufficient for now.

Comment: Yes, but address of A[0] changed. I.e the locations of where A[0] was, changed, I guess thats because of the reallocation.

Comment: I wished to know whether it stores the actual elements in at &A, which I now, don't think it does. My main concern is , if in a multi-dimensional vector A (question 1), I insert elements into the vector A[2] , will there be any memory re-allocation in A ? (there can be memory re-allocation in A[2]. But the number of vectors in A hasn't changed, so I was confirming if there will be re-allocation in A).

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I had this concern because . In my application I have n 1-d vectors each of whose size may change dynamically during run-time . But the number n is fixed. So I am thinking of using a 2-d vector for it. (earlier I was confused whether I should store the pointers to the n 1-d vectors instead due to fear of re-allocation in the parent vector , due to re-allocations in the child vector).

Comment: @ameyask86: I wouldn't resort to raw pointers. As long as the outer vector doesn't grow (is fixed at `n`) then the inner vectors won't move. Each "row" might reallocate the memory it owns but the vector object itself won't move.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Yes, of course. I was letting C programming take over my brain for a second (i.e. `a[b]` <=> `*(a + b)`, which is not true in C++).

Comment: "You might want reconsider whether you really want to look under the hood" I disagree on that one. It's always worth to know what's happening under the hood. For understanding. For improving your own skills. And for knowing what's going on when the abstractions become leaky (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in c++ and STL, so I just test your problem with some simple codes;
first, i have these codes:

```
std::vector<int> tmp;
std::cout << sizeof(tmp) << " " << tmp.size() << " " << tmp.capacity << std::endl;
```

the output is:

```
12 0 0
```

then, we insert some values into the vector

```
for(int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) tmp.push_back(i);
std::cout << sizeof(tmp) << " " << tmp.size() << " " << tmp.capacity << std::endl;
```

the output is

```
12 10 16
```

then, we can draw a conclusion that the vector just keep a pointer, so the sizeof() result didn't changed.
So, the answer of your question is , the child vector's push_back will not result in the reallocation of the parent vector(i don't know how to express the role of these two vectors).
There are some simple codes:

```
std::vector<int> v1(10);
std::vector<int> v2(10);

int i;
for(i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    v1[i] = i;
for(i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    v2[i] = i;

vv.push_back(v1);
vv.push_back(v2);

std::cout << "v1 capacity: " << v1.capacity() << "  v1 size: " << v1.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "v2 capacity: " << v2.capacity() << "  v2 size: " << v2.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "vv capacity: " << vv.capacity() << "  vv size: " << vv.size() << std::endl;

for(i = 10; i != 20; ++i)
    v1.push_back(i);
for(i = 10; i != 20; ++i)
    v2.push_back(i);

std::cout << "v1 capacity: " << v1.capacity() << "  v1 size: " << v1.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "v2 capacity: " << v2.capacity() << "  v2 size: " << v2.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "vv capacity: " << vv.capacity() << "  vv size: " << vv.size() << std::endl;
```

output:

```
v1 capacity: 10  v1 size: 10
v2 capacity: 10  v2 size: 10
vv capacity: 2  vv size: 2
v1 capacity: 20  v1 size: 20
v2 capacity: 20  v2 size: 20
vv capacity: 2  vv size: 2
```